# In eclipse have to manually import packages for servlet tomcat 10

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

i have create a servlet in eclipse and server is tomcat 10 .and  import package is  javax by default  ...

i have to change it to jakarta.servlet.http.   etc. manually   why not by default i am getting Jakarta tomcat servlet-api.jar content ...

in servlet i can change it , but how can i change it for jsp

i am getting by default javax.servlet.http.etc..  not jakarta.servlet.http. even at the time of project creation i choose tomcat 10  ..
but still eclipse provide tomcat syntax ..
i want my  eclipse must be configure for tomcat 10  and import liberaries as jakarta.servlet.http.

Answer (score 1):

Support to do that for Servlets automatically [hasn't been implemented yet](https://bugs.eclipse.org/565498). You'll have to Organize Imports. For JSPs you'll just need the 2021-03 release, WTP 3.21.

Comment: thank you    , here how can i know that what new things and changes are mad ?,,  i am beginner  all is from you guys and youtube @!!!!!!

Comment: Changes can usually be tracked by CCing yourself on the relevant bug. New features can be found in the "New and Noteworthy" link over on the right side of https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/, but that's a tricky point where a lot of the support that's done for JSPs is meant to be invisible when it's working right.